# Console.log() prints state and value of a promise object in Q

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

When I try print a promise object from Q, I got the following result.

```
var Q = require('q');
var defaultPromise = new Q();
console.log('defaultPromise', defaultPromise);

defaultPromise { state: 'fulfilled', value: undefined }
```

Where do the field state, and value come from, I try to find them through visual studio code, the fields are not there.

Comment: Don't know anything about Q but these properties seem to be the return value of its constructor.

Comment: I can see over a dozen references to `state` in the source code for Q, and a lot more for the `value` property - are you looking at q.js? as a side note: Q fails promise aplus test at [2.3.1](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-48) - so, it's not Promise/A+ compliant :p

Comment: I don't think you need to use `new` with `q`.

Answer (score 5):

> A promise must be in one of three states: pending, fulfilled, or rejected.
>
> A promise must provide a then method to access its current or eventual value or reason.

[Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-11)

`Q(value)` returns a promise that is fulfilled with value. In your case, undefined.
[Q API Reference](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qvalue)